# Force classes to implement Serializable for Tomcat Session Replication

Tags: java, spring, session, replication, tomcat8

I am implementing tomcat session replication for achieving load balancing between cluster however replication needs all objects in session to be Serializable.

There are lots of classes which were not Serilazable and stored in session before cluster and we changed to implement Serilazable however it might happen as future classes are added, someone might miss out Serializable and this would result in error while session replication.

I was thinking to extend HttpSession implementation provided by tomcat and override setAttribute to intake Serializable object as parameter however the interface method takes Object as param so it is not possible.

is there way where I can force all classes that would be put into session be Serilazable at compile time ?

We are using spring 4. I wonder think aspect would help ?

Answer (score 0):

I would **neither recommend Java Serialization nor session replication**. That notwithstanding:

If the class is extendable that you can subclass it with a class that also implements `Serializable`. None of the base classes fields will be serialised, of course. You will need a custom `readObject` and `writeObject` to perform these actions.

To do it dynamically, then presumably you wouldd need some filter mechanism to replace objects as they go in and out of the session.

Comment: We did thought of avoiding session replication and go with spring sessions however majority didn't feel so. Now we are stuck with replication. Subclassing would work but that would still need everyone to know about it. For filter part, if I identify the object is not Serializable, how do dynamically make it ? Byte instrumentation ?

Comment: @GautamTadigoppula You could add the `implements Serializable` at code loading time (not as late as when it goes into the session) with a `Java agent`. Fortunately just adding a no-method interface isn't a large modification to an class file (with a suitable library). But what I was thinking, was replacing the object with one of a different class when inserting it into the session. New class just needs class name and a map of fields to values. Details are dependent on your value objects.